# Run action after Gtk window is shown

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I have a multi-window Gtk application, which is an installer.
During the installation process, which takes some time, I want to show a Window with a label to notify the user that the installation is in progress.
So I tried to bind the respective method to the *show* event.

However, that causes the appearance of the window to be delayed until the the method finishes, after which the next window is immediately shown.
The result is, that the previous window shows, then the screen goes blank for the duration of the actual installation and then the final window is shown.

I boiled the issue down to the fact, that the *show* event is obviously triggered, before the window is actually shown.

Here's a minimal snipped to clarify my issue.
The window shows after the call to `sleep()`, not before.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from time import sleep

from gi import require_version
require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


class GUI(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        """Initializes the GUI."""
        super().__init__(title='Gtk Window')
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(self.grid)
        self.label = Gtk.Label()
        self.label.set_text('Doing stuff')
        self.grid.attach(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.connect('show', self.on_show)

    def on_show(self, *args):
        print('Doing stuff.')
        sleep(3)
        print('Done stuff.')


def main() -> None:
    """Starts the GUI."""

    win = GUI()
    win.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can I achieve, that the window shows *before* the method `on_show()` is called?

The desired program flow is

1. Show window
2. run installation
3. hide window (and show next one)

without any user interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using multiprocessing :

```
from ast import Gt
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process

from gi import require_version
require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


class GUI(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        """Initializes the GUI."""
        super().__init__(title='Gtk Window')
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(self.grid)
        self.label = Gtk.Label()
        self.label.set_text('Doing stuff')
        self.grid.attach(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

def on_show():
    print('Doing stuff.')
    sleep(3)
    print('Done stuff.')

        


def main() -> None:
    """Starts the GUI."""

    win = GUI()
    win.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all() 
    p1 = Process(target = on_show)
    p1.start()
    Gtk.main()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Basically, what was happening is that Gtk.main() renders your app while show_all() just packs the widgets, so putting a sleep func before it delays the render.

Comment: That seems kind of hacky. I'd rather have a solution based on the Gtk event model, rather than introducing the complexity of multiprocessing into my program.

Comment: As explained, events delay the call of Gtk.main(), you can try it yourself by calling your on_show() function at differents moments of main().

Comment: Well it's not perfect, but the best solution I have at this moment.

Comment: have you seen my second answer, about threading ? it might be better for your use since its "integrated" to the gtk app and not simultaneous

Answer (score 0):

another method is to use threading (which also provides you an easy way to implemant a progress bar) :

```
from ast import Gt
from time import sleep

import threading

from gi import require_version
require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


class GUI(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        """Initializes the GUI."""
        super().__init__(title='Gtk Window')
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(self.grid)
        self.label = Gtk.Label()
        self.label.set_text('Doing stuff')
        self.grid.attach(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.on_show)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    def on_show(self, *args):
        print('Doing stuff.')
        sleep(3)
        print('Done stuff.')

        


def main() -> None:
    """Starts the GUI."""

    win = GUI()
    win.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all() 
    Gtk.main()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[Further informations on threads](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/threading.html)